# How to save data with EF in the right way (multiple tables)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For Example you have two tables you which are connected (code first) by a ICollection property.

```
public class EntityEnviroment
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int env_id { get; set; }

    public virtual string env_name { get; set; }

    public virtual string env_country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StcEntityFailedReportDetail> failedReportDetails { get; set; }
}

public class EntityFailedReportDetail
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int failed_reports_details_id { get; set; }

    public virtual int report_id { get; set; }

    public virtual string report_status { get; set; }

    public virtual StcEntityEnviromentStatus StcEntityEnviromentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

For one  table I create a instance of the context and on for my entry and the I add it. At last I save it. For multiple tables I did this:

```
        using (var db = new StatusPlatformContext())
        {
            var entryDetail = new EntityFailedReportDetail();
            foreach (var value in result.failed_report_details)
            {

                entryDetail.report_id = value.report_id;
                entryDetail.report_status = value.report_status;

                db.StcEntityFailedReportDetails.Add(entryDetail);

            }

            var entry = new EntityEnviroment
            {
                env_name = result.environment_status.env_name,
                env_country = "Ger",
                failedReportDetails = new List<EntityFailedReportDetail> { entryDetail }
            };
            entryDetail.EntityEnviroment = entry;
            db.EntityEnviromentStat.Add(entry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If I do it like this only the last entry of the details are saved. If I add a db.SaveChanges() to the foreach I will just get an entry in the foreigen key column for the last of the three detail rows.

How I should structure the code? All examples I found just show one table not multiple. Is there any example with a pattern what I should read?

Thanks

Comment: I have two links about insert with multiple tables using EF and Bulk. I hope help you. https://gist.github.com/Boggin/763dbaf1b760bb298156 and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `var entryDetail = new EntityFailedReportDetail();` why is it not in your foreach loop? You need to persist `entryDetail` as well

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

1) You need to create a new EntityFailedReportDetail for each result.

2) Additionally, add each EntityFailedReportDetail to the EntityEnvironment as they are made.

Try this:

```
        var entry = new EntityEnviroment
        {
            env_name = result.environment_status.env_name,
            env_country = "Ger",
            failedReportDetails = new List<EntityFailedReportDetail>()
        };

        foreach (var value in result.failed_report_details)
        {
            var entryDetail = new EntityFailedReportDetail();
            entryDetail.report_id = value.report_id;
            entryDetail.report_status = value.report_status;

            entry.failedReportDetails.Add(entryDetail);

        }
```

Comment: same to this helped a lot and it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: @0x53olution Glad this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

For entities that contain collections of other entities, you should initialize these collections on construction:

```
public class EntityEnviroment
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int env_id { get; set; }
    public virtual string env_name { get; set; }
    public virtual string env_country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StcEntityFailedReportDetail> failedReportDetails { get; set; } = new List<StcEntityFailedReportDetail>();
}
```

This way you can use these collections on new entities right out of the gate. Anywhere in your code that "sets" a collection should be flagged for investigation. It is not a way to clear a collection from your DB for example so if anywhere other than this (or a constructor) does an `= new List<TEntity>()` that is a problem.

```
var entryDetail = new EntityFailedReportDetail();
foreach (var value in result.failed_report_details)
{
    entryDetail.report_id = value.report_id;
    entryDetail.report_status = value.report_status;
    db.StcEntityFailedReportDetails.Add(entryDetail);
}
```

Your problem with this code is that you are initializing 1 "detail" record, then in a loop, updating it's details and trying to "Add" it to the DbSet. This is one single reference.

Then this code:

```
failedReportDetails = new List<EntityFailedReportDetail> { entryDetail }
```

Would simply initialize a collection with that one reference with the latest detail you added.

Adjusting your example:

```
using (var db = new StatusPlatformContext())
{
    var entry = new EntityEnviroment
    {
        env_name = result.environment_status.env_name,
        env_country = "Ger",
    };

    foreach (var value in result.failed_report_details)
    {
        var entryDetail = new EntityFailedReportDetail
        {
            report_id = value.report_id,
            report_status = value.report_status,
            EntityEnvironment = entry
        };
        entry.failedReportDetails.Add(entryDetail);
    }

    db.EntityEnviromentStat.Add(entry);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You don't need to explicitly add each detail to the context's DbSet of details, and if you don't need to query details outside of the entry, your context doesn't even need a DbSet of details. EF will manage the related entities so you only need DbSets for "top level" entities, basically the parent entities that your system references individually. You can always query related entities through their parents.

Comment: Thank you for your help this explained a lot and it works now.